# The divergence rate of a divergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series

In calculus, we learned how to identify whether a series is convergent or not. However, for a divergent series, we never learned how to obtain how fast it diverges, i.e., how to obtain $d$ defined as follows:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}{N^d}=c,$$
where $a_n\ge 0$ and $c$ is a non-zero constant.

For cases where the sum of the first $N$ terms can be explicitly calculated, find $d$ is easily. For example, for the series $\sum_{n=1}^N n$, we know $d=2$.

I wonder whether there is a general procedure to obtain $d$ analytically for all divergent series. For example,
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n}{N^d}=c,$$

Comment: If $H_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}1/n$ then $H_N\sim \log N$. This shows that for every $d>0$ we have $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{H_N}{N^d}=0$. I.e not all divergent series have polynomial growth.

Comment: the first thing to try is when you are given $a_n = f(n)$ for a continuous $f(x),$ see whether you get closed form for $ \int_0^n f(x) dx$ which will often be a good estimate. Note that your recipe does not work all that well for $a_n = \frac{1}{n \log n}$